# Django retrieving a tables data based on another table

Tags: python, django

I have the following tables:

```
class Note(model):
    note_data = models.ForeignKey(NoteData)
    important = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    deleted = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    deleted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)

class NoteData(model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    note = models.TextField()
```

How do I list all notes by oldest first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Note.objects.all().order_by('note_data__created')
```

This is [fully documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by).

Comment: I know it's fully documented but I find reverse lookup very counter intuitive